# How do I crop/straighten, apply settings, then save and close with Photoshop actions?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have two actions right now. The first crops and straightens the photos from an image. They are scanned pages from a scrapbook. An image might have 4-6 individual images in it. Crop and Straighten works pretty good. I can run that on a folder by going to `File->Automate->Batch` and it works good too.

Once that is done I can run the second action I have to apply some changes, then save the file. I run that the same way, `File->Automate->Batch`, but this time I run it on open files.

So, everything is working fine, but now I have a lot of images I need to process and Photoshop tells me that there are too many files open before it can finish the first action.

How can I join these two actions? I want to process a folder, so that it would open the file, crop and straighten, apply some changes to the newly created files, save those open files, close them, then move onto the next file in the folder.

I feel like this should be simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

[image: Existing actions]

Comment: Combine both actions into a single one? Try running the batches from the folder containing the files? Hard to give you anything more specific unless you show us what you tried and what the specific problem you encountered is.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks for the help. I added a screenshot of the two actions I have. If I combine them, the "Auto" piece will only run on the current file and not on all open files. That's where I get stuck. So, let's say Crop and Straighten creates 5 files, I end up with the original file open, plus 5 more. I want to perform the second action on the 5 new files and not just the one that is "active." Not sure if I'm making sense or not.

Comment: Since the first action generates new files, I would run the second action on a folder containing the files generated by the first one. If you really want to do everything in one go, you'd probably need to make a script that will run both actions one after the other.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The files aren't saved from the first action, until the second action. I think that's my biggest issue. I don't know how to have an action save all open files (without running another batch). I'll look into scripts and see what I can come up with. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post all the step of both actions?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I ended up finding a script here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790392/how-to-automate-photoshop. That did pretty much what I wanted. I added a call to my action to apply the changes I wanted, then save the file. Thanks for giving me a push in the right direction.